# What's the difference between these 2 types of arrow functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vuejs3

I am having trouble understanding why one arrow function will return an array of items while the other doesn't (it's the same function, just in a different format).

**Goal**: This program is supposed to filter through a JSON file to find cocktails that have every ingredient (not strictly *just* the ingredients specified) specified by an array of strings.

Let me share some context as to what one of the JSON file objects looks like (out of over 400+):

```js
{
    "strGlass": "White Wine Glass",
    "idDrink": "15346",
    "strCreativeCommonsConfirmed": "No",
    "strCategory": "Cocktail",
    "strInstructionsIT": "Miscela con ghiaccio.\r\nServire in un bicchiere da vino.\r\nGuarnire con una carota.",
    "strInstructions": "Blend with ice. Serve in a wine glass. Garnish with carrot.",
    "strDrink": "155 Belmont",
    "Ingredients": [
      {
        "Measurement": "1 shot ",
        "Ingredient": "Dark rum"
      },
      {
        "Ingredient": "Light rum",
        "Measurement": "2 shots "
      },
      {
        "Measurement": "1 shot ",
        "Ingredient": "Vodka"
      },
      {
        "Measurement": "1 shot ",
        "Ingredient": "Orange juice"
      }
    ],
    "dateModified": "2016-10-05 12:36:28",
    "strDrinkThumb": "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/yqvvqs1475667388.jpg",
    "strAlcoholic": "Alcoholic",
    "strInstructionsDE": "Mit Eis vermischen. In einem Weinglas servieren. Mit Karotte garnieren."
  }
```

And the array I'm using looks like this:

```js
let Filterable_Drinks = reactive([]);
let Ingredients_Searched_For = reactive(["vodka", "lemonade"]);
```

Here's the **first** format:

```js
Filterable_Drinks.length = 0;

const items = DRINKS.filter(cocktail => Ingredients_Searched_For.every(ing => cocktail.Ingredients.find(cocIng => cocIng.Ingredient.toLowerCase().includes(ing.toLowerCase()))))

Filterable_Drinks.push(...items);
console.log(Filterable_Drinks);
```

And here is the **second** format:

```js
Filterable_Drinks.length = 0;

const items = DRINKS.filter((cocktail) => {
    Ingredients_Searched_For.every((ing) => {
      cocktail.Ingredients.find(cocIng => cocIng.Ingredient.toLowerCase().includes(ing.toLowerCase()))
    })
  })

Filterable_Drinks.push(...items);
console.log(Filterable_Drinks);
```

It seems to be the same thing, but the second one returns an empty array as the **first** one doesn't.

What's the difference between the two different formats of the same code?

Comment: the second format, nothing is returned - because you dont' `return` anything

Comment: Where would I place the return? I appended it to the ```cocIng.Ingredient.toLowerCase().includes(ing.toLowerCase())``` and it still returned an empty array

Comment: `return Ingredients_Searched_For........etc`  best way to understand is by [reading documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions)

Comment: try reading the documentation for a fuller understanding

Comment: It didn't work, it still returned an empty array

Comment: you did it wrong - you need to ALSO add it before `return cocktail.Ingredients.find` - I didn't see that because I wasn't debugging your code for you - basically `() => statement` is equivalent to `() => { return statement;}`

Comment: Please note that if you're using JS, please also get in the habit of using JS conventions for naming things. Variables and functions use lowerCamelCase, constants use UPPER_SNAKE_CASE, classes/constructor function use UpperCamelCase. Don't invent your own conventions: for your sake and everyone who needs to read your code, use the established conventions.